# ReferenceError: navigator is not defined in angular4 with server side rendering

Tags: angular, codemirror, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, simplemde

I am using simpleMDE editor with my angular 4 Server side rendering application and getting the reference of textarea using

```
@ViewChild('simpleMDE') textarea : ElementRef;
```

and initializing it in ngAfterViewInit()

```
   this.simplemde = new SimpleMDE(
      {
          element: this.textarea.nativeElement.value,
      })
```

in Template in am using textarea like this

```
<textarea id="simpleMDE" #simpleMDE></textarea>
```

While starting the server its throwing error saying

```
projectpath\node_modules\codemirror\lib\codemirror.js:11
        typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? module.exports = factory() :
                                                                                 ^
ReferenceError: navigator is not defined
    at projectpath\node_modules\codemirror\lib\codemirror.js:18:17
```

Please suggest something, I stuck here.
 [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/ranavc32/SimpleMDE-angular-universal.git)

Answer (score 2):

As stated in Angular Universal Documentation

window, document, navigator, and other browser types - do not exist on the server - so using them, or any library that uses them (jQuery for example) will not work

If you need to use them, consider limiting them to only your client and wrapping them situationally. You can use the Object injected using the PLATFORM_ID token to check whether the current platform is browser or server.

```
 import { PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
 import { isPlatformBrowser, isPlatformServer } from '@angular/common';

 constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) { ... }

 ngOnInit() {
   if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      // Client only code.
      ...
   }
   if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
     // Server only code.
     ...
   }
 }
```

Will need to manipulate the library :(

Edit:
In following lines error comes from codemirror.js

```
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
var platform = navigator.platform;
```

try manipulating that code

```
if(navigator){
  var userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
  var platform = navigator.platform;
}else{
 var userAgent="server";
 var platform="server";
}
```

P.S : Not sure what would be the impact :D.

Comment: I didn't used it manually, anywhere in code but simpleMDE texteditor uses it internally so may be from there its throwing error.
I will try your solution as soon as i will get back to my machine.
Thanks Man....!!

Comment: @PraveenRana please see edited answer, not sure if it will help to solve the issue.

Comment: Okay , Parth. I will test this piece of code and let you know if this works or not.
Can test only in evening.

Comment: @PraveenRana sure... let me know what happens

Comment: I tried both the approaches. none of these work.
Wrapping my simpleMDE initialization inside isPlatFormBrowser() and changes in codemirror library also..! It still didn't work. Help Bro

Comment: can u create github or something. its not going to work as navigator is undefined in server side. will have to create a workaround based on errors

Comment: Yeah , Sure let me setup github repository for this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141461/discussion-between-praveen-rana-and-parth-ghiya).

Comment: here is git repository link

[Repo](https://github.com/ranavc32/SimpleMDE-angular-universal)

Answer (score 2):

Guess you have code like this in your js/ts files.

```
import CodeMirror from 'codemirror';
```

As answered by @Parth Ghiya, `navigator` is only surpported in browser, this will lead to error.

While trying to support server rendering, you can make some change(lazy require) in your code this way:

```
// just before places where are using codemirror
const CodeMirror = require('codemirror');   
require('codemirror/addon/hint/show-hint');

CodeMirror(...)
```

Comment: Can you take a look at the repository  please https://github.com/ranavc32/SimpleMDE-angular-universal

Comment: @PraveenRana The dependency `simplemde` seems using `codemirror`, and I didn't find any server rendering issues overthere or exactly any words supporting for angular-universal. If you still want to use it with `angular-universal` , you should do changes like I answered to `simplemde` library.

Comment: can you make a pull request to repository according the changes you are saying because i don't know where and what exactly changes I need to make, will be much obliged.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I handle this sorta problem. 
To me, server render is only for SEO purpose. And stuff like codemirror doesn't really do anything with SEO. Therefore, my approach is "not to render it on the server side".

[image] [ref](https://medium.com/burak-tasci/angular-4-with-server-side-rendering-aka-angular-universal-f6c228ded8b0)

The basic structure is like above illustration.

You have 2 boot files, one for server rendering and the other for client rendering.

Therefore, you actually can have different application modules for each boot file.

In the application module for server render, you can use a **mock component** to replace the component that uses browser objects and use the real component for client side.

This way you don't need to worry about the problematic component on server render.

Another solution is to use webpack to handle those browser objects.

something like this [ref](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/308#issuecomment-275361791)

```
module: {
  rules: [
    { 
      test: /@angular(\\|\/)material/, use: "imports-loader?window=>global,CSS=>null,navigator=>{get userAgent(){return Zone.current.get('req')['headers']['user-agent'];}}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Personally, I prefer the first solution. The second is kinda hacky to me and rendering a component that has nothing to do with SEO on server side doesn't really give us any benefit.

Answer (score 0):

To make it simple, just put

```
global['navigator'] = {} or global['navigator'] = {  userAgent: ''};

// ...
```

at the top of the server.ts file. This way, it will ignore the error.